# How to extract an individual item of an EntityCollection thru xaml binding?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, xaml, indexer, navigation-properties

I have a Contact entity that exposes a navigation proeprty for child Phone entities.

```
Public Class Contact : Inherits EntityObject    
    Public Property Phones() As EntityCollection(Of Phone)
EndClass
```

I want to Xamly retrieve the first phone of the bound contact.
I tried the following but it doesn't work.
Note: I also tried Phones[0] (I use VB).

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type data:Contact}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Phones(0)}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Any suggestions (either in VB or C# will be welcommed)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [this](http://silverlight.net/forums/p/93093/282694.aspx) link I found interesting solutions.

I am still opened to hear about new 'Xamly' ideas, that doesn't have to involve converters etc.

TheJeffro's one looks the best, and this is what I am using till further posts.